# WinDbg scripting - how to delete a file?

Tags: windbg

I'm working with an existing framework of WinDbg scripts that go through a series of test scripts Test1.txt, Test2.txt, etc., which are generated by C++ code and which output results.

For example a chunk of one of the test scripts would be,

```
 .if (($spat(@"${var}","18300.000000")==1))
        {
            .logappend C:\Tests\TestResults.txt
            .printf "TestNumber=\t1\tExpected=\t18300.000000\tActual=\t%.6f\t******PASSED******\n",poi(poi(@$t2+@$t6)+0x10)
            .logclose
        }
```

I'm trying to add functionality that will create a file whose name displays the current # of the test being run, so that users can see their progress without needing to open a file.

My thought process was that I would set up the script generator, so that at the start of Test #N, it would add a line to the script to create a file 'currentlyRunningTestN.txt', and at the end of Test #N, it would add a line to the script to delete that file.  However, I don't see any delete function in the WinDbg meta command glossary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/meta-commands, or in the list of supported C functions like printf.  Am I just missing something, or is deleting files not supported by WinDbg (or equivalently renaming files, which would also serve my purpose?)  If deleting/renaming don't work, is there another way to achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: Sorry your Query is unclear can you rephrase or rather why do you want to create and delete a dummy file is your user going to watch the directory for creation of a named dummy file ?  leagcy windbg doesnt have file creation capability  if you have access to windbg preview you can use javascript to create and delete file  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dbgmodel-namespace-file-system

Comment: My user will be running a series of the scripts and want to be able to see which script is currently being run without opening a file, so that's why I want to create and delete the dummy file.  It seems like I can create a file in my current version of WinDbg with .logappend, but not delete it which seems like a strange omission.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`.shell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-shell--command-shell-) command, you can execute any DOS-like command. Although I never tried deleting a file, it should be possible.

As you may have noticed, WinDbg scripting does not always work on first attempt, please make sure your scripting will not result in a big data loss on your customer's PC whilst deleting files.